# The usage and meaning of the infinitive --the unpleasant 'to discover' in this sentence

Tags: phrase-usage, infinitives

I come across the following sentences. Please explain the usage of this infinitive. Does 'to discover' work as an adjective qualifying the noun 'the unpleasant occasion'? I want to know what does  **the unpleasant occasion to discover** mean in this sentence. If you have any good ideas, please let me know.

> Cleanliness is considered a virtue, but just what does it mean to be
> clean? As most of us have had **the unpleasant occasion to discover**,
> one person’s definition can be quite different from another’s.

Answer (score 1):

Most dictionaries define [have occasion to do something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/had+occasion+to) as *need to do it*, but the meaning can be broader than that. In this case, the sense is "Most of us have had moments when we discovered, in an unpleasant way, that someone else's idea of 'clean' is different from ours".

Comment: Thank you for the answering comment. I just want to know what "in an unpleasant way" mean in this case.  Do you mean " it can be seen as conflicting with one's own values and that can be deeply felt at times"?  I'm afraid I don't understand what @Kate Bunting explain. Thanks again.

Comment: I thought you were asking about the use of the infinitive **to discover**. The sentence is suggesting that it would be unpleasant to be given something to use that was supposedly clean, but that was not quite clean by your own standards - for instance, a towel that had been washed but had stains on it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The example was very clear and deepened my understanding. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To "have occasion" to do something can either mean to have the opportunity to do something, or that something actually occurred. In this case, it means it actually occurred.

So "*As most of us have had the unpleasant occasion to discover, ...*" means roughly:

> As most of use have unpleasantly discovered, ...

Comment: The paraphrasing has deepened my understanding. Thank you very much！